# Scrollview with React Native isn't scrolling

Tags: javascript, react-native, scrollview

I am currently working on a react native project which requires me to make a profile page.  Im trying to use scrollview to render an image with words underneath it.  Here is my code:

```
// @flow

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native';

//import PictureScroller from './PictureScroller';
//import TaggButton from './TaggButton';
import styles from './styles';

//import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

type Props = {
  images: Object,
  name: String,
}

const Profile = (props: Props) => {

    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView} contentContainerStyle={{flex:1}}>
        <Image source={props.images}/>
        <Text style={styles.name}>props.name</Text>
      </ScrollView>
      );
    }



export default Profile;
```

Please let me know if I should include additional code.

Comment: try `<Image style={{width: 1000, height: 500}} />`. you will see it scroll

Comment: @Val still not scrolling, thanks any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The contentContainerStyle `flex:1` is the problem here.

Just remove contentContainerStyle or change `flex:1` in contentContainerStyle to `flexGrow:1`. You should be able to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of `styles.scrollView`? This should have `flex: 1`.

Comment: flex: 1 and backgroundColor: 'white'

Answer (score 0):

or else try this

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
 <ScrollView>
    <Image source={props.images}/>
    <Text style={styles.name}>props.name</Text>
 </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Comment: I tried implementing this and it quickly scrolls but immediately snaps back to the normal page and does not perform the scroll again.